# running Procedure by Trigger on new data in OracleDB

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers

I wrote a procedure to update a table by deriving its data from four other tables. The procedure itself works fine, but I need the table to be up to date all the time, so I call the procedure from triggers which fire, whenever one of the four tables ist altered. 
This too works fine except for one detail. The procedure derives the data from the tables BEFORE the changes, so the update/delete/insert, which fired the trigger.
The trigger is rowlevel after u/d/i but even changing it to after statement did not help.
Not using a trigger is not really an option, because of the need being in sync. Changing it to a materialized view seems to be a good idea, but neede calculations are disallowed in those and nonmaterialized views are too slow, which is why I want to change it from a nonmaterialized view to a table. 
Handing all information about what was changed in which way over to the procedure would be possible, but it would make the procedure so much more complicated, that I refrain from writing this code.

Is there any way to derive my table based on the new values directly triggered by a change in the four tables?

Regards
Ramin